# get the count of columns contains a string in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have two dataframes df1 and df2.

df1:

```
PartNumber
0000D3447E
0000D3447E
0000D3447E12
0000D3447E
0000D3447E
0000D3447E
0000D3447E2345
0000F2892E
0000F2892E
0000F2892E
0000F2892E34
0000F2892E
0000F2892E
0000F2892E12
```

df2:

```
PartNumber
0000D3447E39S
0000D3447E39S
0000D3447E39S
0000D3447E39S
0000D3447E39S
0000D3447E39S
0000D3447E39S2245
0000F2892EDI1
0000F2892EDI1
0000F2892EDI1
0000F2892EDI124
0000F2892EDI1
0000F2892EDI1
0000F2892EDI1
0000D1617EAD6
0000D1617EAD6
0000D1617EAD6137
0000D1617EAD6
0000D1617EAD6
0000D1617EAD612
0000D1617EAD6
0000D3447EYG1
0000D3447EYG1
0000D3447EYG1
0000D3447EYG1
0000D3447EYG1
0000D3447EYG1
0000D3447EYG1
```

i need to take '0000D3447E' from df1 and get the column count of df2 which contains this string and update the count in df1 by creating a new column.

the given answer    df1['count_of_colors'] = df1['PartNumber'].map(df2['PartNumber'].str[:10].value_counts())
 may solve the problem but the string is not constant with 10 characters.So, i'm getting the wrong count of the strings because the string is restricted is str[:10] characters.

Thanks.

Comment: Consider accepting the answer that correctly solves your issue. If neither do, please add expected output. I personally struggle with the fact that you provided sample data that would count to zero..Consider updating the data in the question before adding expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use map

```
df1['count_of_colors'] = df1['PartNumber'].map(df2['PartNumber'].str[:10].value_counts())
```

df1:

```
    PartNumber  count_of_colors
0   0000D3447E  14
1   0000D3447E  14
2   0000D3447E  14
3   0000D3447E  14
4   0000D3447E  14
5   0000D3447E  14
6   0000D3447E  14
7   0000F2892E  7
8   0000F2892E  7
9   0000F2892E  7
10  0000F2892E  7
11  0000F2892E  7
12  0000F2892E  7
13  0000F2892E  7
```

EDIT: Use str.extract to extract the exact match in df2 and then use same solution

```
pat = '({})'.format('|'.join(df1['PartNumber'].unique()))

df2['PartMatch'] = df2['PartNumber'].str.extract(pat, expand = False)

df1['count_of_colors'] = df1['PartNumber'].map(df2['PartMatch'].value_counts())
```

You get the same output and its not hard-coded for the number of characters

Comment: in the answer the string length is restricted to "str[:10]". Can you pls tell me how can i take the whole string from df1?
like 
df1['count_of_colors'] = df1['PartNumber'].map(df2['PartNumber'].str[:len(df2['PartNumber'].str)].value_counts())

Comment: i have tried this. but it is not giving me any count.

Comment: I'm not getting any error. The script passed but I'm not seeing any counts updated in the dataframe.

Comment: Its working with the sample df you have posted. Difficult to trouble shoot, if the problem is not reproducible

Comment: Thank you Vaishali. It is working now. I made a mistake that's why it didn't work earlier.

Comment: If the issue is resolved, do accept the answer. It will help even those who come to this link later

Answer (score 0):

I think u only need this

```
df1['count_of_colors'] =df1['PartNumber'].map(df2['PartNumber'].value_counts())
```

Comment: i have tried this. but it is also not giving me any count

Answer (score 0):

My code is here. It works for me.. I could not copy all the data that u gave, but a sample is here

```
import pandas as pd
df1= pd.DataFrame(["0000D3447E","0000F2892E"])
df1.columns=['data']
df2=pd.DataFrame(["0000D3447E","0000D3447E","0000D3447E","0000D3447E","0000F2892E"])
df2.columns=['data']

df1['count']= df1['data'].map(df2['data'].value_counts())

df1
```

Comment: For me the 'count' column is empty when I use this code

Comment: Thank you emdi. Thanks for your help.